# Export Robotium test cases into Appium

Tags: android, automation, robotium, appium

Is it possible to export test cases written with Robotium into Appium?
Until now I used Robotium to test an Android app, but I want to switch to Appium and not loose my work.

Answer (score -1):

There is no straight forward method to do this yet. You will have to port over the changes manually. There shouldn't be a lot of changes. You'll mostly have to move the R.* to using Selendroid for it.